# Firestore query by document Id and another property

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to know if it is possible to do the following query, using the Id of the document and another property.

```
await firestore
  .collection('organizations')
  .doc(props.organizationId)
  .where('members', 'array-contains', userId)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `FieldPath.documentId()` to filter on the document ID in a query. So:

```
await firestore
  .collection('organizations')
  .where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), '==', props.organizationId)
  .where('members', 'array-contains', userId)
```

Comment: Can you contrast this with getting the doc and checking its data?

Comment: Nice to know @Frank!

Comment: @danh: this gives you a `QuerySnapshot` which is typically easier for when you want to show a list in the UI (even if it's a list of one). Aside from that, it's the same.